# Comparison of string "0" in PHP

Tags: php

consider both the sinppets in php:

`$x = "0"; if($x){// do something}`

`$x = "1"; if($x){ ... }`

Here `$x="0"` will return value as false when compared, while assignment of `$x="1"` will return true.Why is it like that?

Comment: [PHP Manual on Converting to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)

Comment: PHP is weakly typed. That's why those "strings" aren't strings in the condition context. Depending on the context, the values are either interpreted as numbers or strings. `if($x)` in this case will coerce them to boolean expressions after evaluating values as numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> [...]
>
> the empty string, and the string "0"

Answer (score 3):

It is like that because it is written in [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- **the empty string, and the string "0"**
- an array with zero elements
- an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

Your case is the string "0".

Most of the times if you have a strange behavior the first thing to go is to documentation and to read everything, after that check a bug report with similar names. After this it makes sense to ask on stackoverflow or to make your [own bug report](https://bugs.php.net/).